Make an enemy move back and forth
I am trying to make it so an enemy would move back and form from one position to the next. I am using the Ping Pong method and that does not seem to work.
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float movementSpeed = 5.0f;

    Vector2 pointA;
    Vector2 pointB;

    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb=GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        pointA = new Vector2(9, 0);
        pointB = new Vector2(2, 0);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float move = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * movementSpeed, 1);
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(pointA, pointB, move);
    }
}

What i expected is just like i said.
for the object move back and forth

in general you shouldn't mix Rigidbody and movement through Transform as this will break physics and collision detection

I just tested your code and for me it works fine. This is what I ended up using
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 a = new Vector2(0, 0);
    Vector2 b = new Vector2(0, 5);
    float movementSpeed = 2f;

    private void Update()
    {
        float move = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * movementSpeed, 1);
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(a, b, move);
    }
}

Are you sure its the code itself that is wrong? Could it be something else in the game engine that isnt set up properly, for example, have you attached this script as a component to the object you want to move? Are there any other scripts that could affect this objects position? I dont think the issue is in this piece of code, the problem comes from somewhere else.

It was the use of rigidbody. I just removed it and it worked just fine
